# Render Home Screen based of different profile type from firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Flutter. In a nutshell, I have a School Management app and in that i have different user models in that such as Principle, Student, Teachers.
[image]
As one can see all models have different properties except one 'profileType'. If anyone want to see my firestore arrangement, click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ntQIFUArjHwdB66di4VoIlwfniPhI6gd/view?usp=sharing).
Now, at login page user will select his school, enter username and password. Now what i want is, to render homepage according to the Profile Type. Student page for Student and so on.
The full Repo is [here](https://github.com/sumitt1080/E-School). I'm really stuck here and actually have no idea to achieve this.
If someone can point me to a good tutorial, that too is enough.

Comment: you don't have make the profiletype string, make them `enum` it will be more easy to compare and you dont have make 3 models you just need one model and while fetching the different data for some profiles that will be null so you even don't need that. Now while logging in you have to define the role of the user so I think you need a database

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using different classes with the same kind of data, Make use of enum to select the type of profile and work with it accordingly

```
enum ProfileType{STUDENT,PRINCIPAL,TEACHER}
```

Now you can make a single class as Profile and in place of String profileType now use

```
ProfileType profileType;
```

if you need some extra parameters for student or teacher or principal then add extension to class Profile and add your parameters.
`class Student extends Profile{}`